# How can I download the YouTube URLs using edx-dl

Tags: python, edx

I am using [edx-dl](https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl) to download my videos from edX. 
Now, I am wondering, how I can also download each YouTube link as a seperate text file.

I tried:
edx-dl -u USERNAME COURSE_URL --youtube-dl-options g

but it does not work.

I would not like to change the edx-dl code to be able to update it if needed.

edit> SIMILAR QUESTION> [Download edX Video Subscriot and YouTUbe URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686824/download-edx-video-subscriot-and-youtube-url)

Comment: you can use yt-dl (https://yt-dl.org/)

Comment: @OlegButuzov Yes, but how do I get the video links from the edx videos

Answer (score 1):

I am kinda struggling to find course with youtube videos in it.

Currently:

```
edx-dl -u=login -p=pass https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/course/ --dry-run
edx_dl version 0.1.11
Building initial headers for future requests.
Getting initial CSRF token.
Found CSRF token.
Logging into Open edX site: https://courses.edx.org/login_ajax
Extracting course information from dashboard.
Downloading Amazon DynamoDB: Building NoSQL Database-Driven Applications [course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/co]
Downloading 5 section(s)
Section  1: Welcome to Amazon DynamoDB: Building NoSQL Database-Driven Applications
  Welcome to Amazon DynamoDB: Building NoSQL Database-Driven Applications
  Course Welcome and Student Information
  Course Wiki
  Meet the Instructors
  Introduce Yourself
Section  2: Week 1
  What Are We Building? Exercise Architecture
  Introduction to Week 1
  Relational Databases and the Problem that Need Solving
  How Most NoSQL Databases Work
  Introduction to Amazon DynamoDB
  Amazon DynamoDB Demo (Part 1)
  Amazon DynamoDB Demo (Part 2)
  Introduction to Exercise 1
  Exercise 1
  Introduction to Exercise 2
  Exercise 2
  Week 1 Notes and Resources
  Week 1 Quiz
  Week 1 Discussion
Section  3: Week 2
  Introduction to Week 2
  Backing Up and Restoring an Amazon DynamoDB Table
  Backing Up/Restoring Demonstration
  Amazon DynamoDB API Working with Datasets
  Introduction to Exercise 3
  Exercise 3
  Monitoring Amazon DynamoDB (Part 1)
  Monitoring Amazon DynamoDB (Part 2)
  Introduction to Exercise 4
  Exercise 4
  Partition Keys and How They Impact Performance
  Week 2 Notes and Resources
  Week 2 Quiz
  Week 2 Discussion
Section  4: Week 3
  Introduction to Week 3
  Encryption and Compliance
  Stateless Applications
  Introduction to Exercise 5
  Exercise 5
  Access Controls - IAM and VPC Endpoints
  Introduction to Exercise 6
  Exercise 6
  Global Tables
  Streams
  Streams for ES for Full Text Searching
  Week 3 Notes and Resources
  Week 3 Quiz
  Week 3 Discussion
Section  5: Week 4
  Introduction to Week 4
  Optimistic Locking
  LSI and GSI In-depth
  Amazon DynamoDB API - Writing Better Queries
  Introduction to Exercise 7
  Exercise 7
  Single Table
  Time Series
  Introduction to Exercise 8
  Exercise 8
  DAX
  Week 4 Notes and Resources
  Week 4 Quiz
  Class Wrap Up
  Course Survey
  Week 4 Discussion
Extracting all units information in parallel.
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@c72080a313c74d0dae0b39392e4e53c7'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@d6f3cdb66f5341c28f4f0d4f31757fce'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@81cecad59f874dc297ebe7180d88cf4c'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@f4eb60e5df704770bf8cde43371eec28'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@f0657885db5c4753a74f026f5e9de3c5'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@03f6efa2dbd84c009e67d88af1c967da'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@f00d3f37945c4e41909705d7b602004d'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@91fc759562c949bfacaceac11a74f80c'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@468b054704c84068bdf181ccb045f81e'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@d176736563764741b4555be1698d0dc9'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@51e271a1c69a45768ed57a06585a5873'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@31cbef2cd8ea4992b24dbcc0f32c9386'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@385285e549a54759bd72c8826729a9d9'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@625c08d8e3244dac9fa817c2ec25121a'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@3f7ae64e6b394488bb6ba579c9d31e4e'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@5f2a2547c5ec4c5e9d1a5bc5c1bb490a'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@38229ea14cba4aeb9132b8f20fe9818b'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@68aebc2dcd174efdb24f24a7cba25c4f'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@4026b0d52b3145c3b056e8a0849f1a03'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@1fc522a40594470d891a27ce8a9f9821'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@0c560edd7b5847b38b9df5ef7e83d4bc'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@f06bf048726f4ae4a1d958f4662a116a'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@8b47a15c1e12452f8052bc96d61f65e7'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@43ecec1dff9b49d1a12286b2e1477090'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@a6d401fc5ce34ef7bd990846a7d230b9'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@79627578969d45cab2608f84a4164e5b'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@6f1de7310d8748419f1a5477f8b7b8f9'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@f500d7d796cd426b99a04d0b2398d509'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@9df7a1919ce245b78dc2af61b9d3388d'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@77f597c99a564bf0b8962c7b7c1bf936'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@a072704cebf34da6ae876bec848d6c1c'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@376dcd63618d4a4fb2a1ac00602aeecc'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@75938c7d72ec495c85154b0bfc75151c'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@a3c6fb8271de4239b3ae748532bf2614'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@ca5ea4df82c04be7b76496f9b3bea46e'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@7d20d3a3eea649a4bd3887f72d6ae831'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@2b3c50bc81494875aef54317ec7f9cd5'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@08bc78e2759a426ab3a469477ef2ba77'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@574ab94d374e473f951ff69abde9d4d3'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@e5c9b39cca1d4eaaa33314904b7eaa74'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@591ce1fa1b4f4aa9a78fe6a3e0496e6f'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@7cb2a15f999148298cf2c991666f2a68'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@3e295383732449949f5d483f1c212f0c'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@68f7826787b04f2db0f649b7e70f0ce7'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@bb7ffc8d47b84cbf93d0b3c631d69a9e'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@4ad9a6058d7a45b1a9421e73c7efb429'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@5834d839679b48cd808437a9a47c1719'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@43a0d84c71c44851906f47d5958519de'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@9322861714c64d1d8a15d2c284c7a70d'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@b80d2f0acef042f7a239350bc2986291'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@c494e50e17fc4ba1b86049e64d5c1d00'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@963315857d374fd39532d04dfe60815f'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@38bd044198b34fe983996be2913600b0'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@812a8ce1f4dd42dfa81c15e7bb49b322'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@c87e32aae53b46eabcebaf2b19488644'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@f1f1646140a34f42ade59df757305802'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@10ae4c5e6f0546bd88600f5a807b31a4'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@1649837d03be4758946782b50ba2ed85'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@1bba86e73f5d4fd787b21e1f18e90613'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@55906a3b59f4432db5053d94016574d1'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@4249022eda2f47eba8ff1c6c9f9c2bbe'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@fc15173f7c32410e832028c78e159655'
Processing 'https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019/jump_to/block-v1:AWS+OTP-AWS-D6+2T2019+type@vertical+block@e18d6be3284b47d8a51e0820fbb0d274'
Removed 555 duplicated urls from 669 in total
Output directory: Downloaded
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003700_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/01-Welcome_to_Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/01-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003700_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003500_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/01-Welcome_to_Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003500_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003600_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/01-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003600_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004500_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/02-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004500_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003900_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/03-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003900_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003800_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/04-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003800_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003200_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/05-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003200_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003400_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/06-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003400_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003300_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/07-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003300_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003000_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/08-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003000_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003100_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/02-Week_1/09-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V003100_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004000_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/01-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004000_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002400_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/02-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002400_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002300_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/03-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002300_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002600_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/04-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002600_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002200_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/05-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002200_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002500_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/06-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002500_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002900_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/07-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002900_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002700_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/08-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002700_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002800_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/03-Week_2/09-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002800_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004200_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/01-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004200_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002100_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/02-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002100_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001700_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/03-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001700_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001300_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/04-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001300_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001900_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/05-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001900_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002000_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/06-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V002000_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001600_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/07-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001600_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001400_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/04-Week_3/08-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001400_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004100_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/01-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004100_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001000_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/02-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001000_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001100_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/03-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001100_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004900_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/04-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004900_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V000900_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/05-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V000900_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004700_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/06-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004700_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004600_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/07-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V004600_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V000800_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/08-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V000800_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001500_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/09-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V001500_DTH.mp4
[download] https://edx-video.net/AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V005000_DTH.mp4 => Downloaded/Amazon_DynamoDB-_Building_NoSQL_Database-Driven_Applications/05-Week_4/10-AWSOTP-AWS-D6-V005000_DTH.mp4
```

Check the last section with links to videos in it.